# Audio ducking stops when AVAssetWriter.startWriting is called

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avassetwriter

We have an app where we play some audio while ducking any sounds from other apps that might be playing (music, spotify, etc).

This works most of the time and external audio is ducked properly. However whenever we call on an AVAssetWriter instance to startWriting, the ducking stops entirely and never resumes. The only way to resume it seems to be stopping the session and restarting it, setting the category again doesn't do anything. Has anyone run into similar problems with ducking and have any solutions? Thanks!

`...
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .spokenAudio, options: [.duckOthers, .interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers])
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
...
    self.assetWriter.startWriting()
...`